# Package with debconf preselections

Tags: debian, packaging

I'd like to create a package which will depend on mysql-server and set the password to its own randomly generated string in case the server is not installed yet.
I don't want to have the user put in the password and I'm happy to get the current password from the debconf's file.

But how can I guarantee that my package presets `mysql-server-5.1/root_password` before the `mysql-server` package is installed? `mysql-server` is listed as a dependency of my package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot guarantee that. In fact, it is guaranteed to work exactly the other direction.  From http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html:

> The meaning of the five dependency fields is as follows:
>
> Depends
>
> This declares an absolute dependency. A package will not be configured unless all of the packages listed in its Depends field have been correctly configured (unless there is a circular dependency as described above).

Your best bet is to make your package work *after* MySQL is properly installed--possibly by resetting the password, if you really need that functionality.